# why this code fails after a specific value

Tags: c

The code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef struct lb_data_US
    {
        char uname[255];
        char Eid[4];
        char myrole[4];
        char Login_t[30];
        char Logout_t[30];
        char ClientIP[20];
        char ZoneName[256];
    };

    int x = atoi(argv[1]);
    lb_data_US  lb_local[x];
    printf("stands for %d value\n", x);
    exit(0);
}
```

When I run this code using `./structure_testop 20995`, it runs completely but when i run this code with a larger argument (like 20996 or more), it fails occasionally...
When i tried to debug it by gdb it says

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x003d6773 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=<value optimized out>, format=<value optimized out>, ap=<value optimized out>)
at vfprintf.c:233
233       int save_errno = errno;
Current language:  auto; currently c"
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I do not believe that is your complete source code.

Comment: yes actually i was asked to debug a large code...and i came to the conclusion that that code has a very similar condition where it fails..

Comment: What compiler and OS are you using and how did you compile this code?

Comment: g++ compiler and i actually compiled by this coomand....."g++ -o testfile_op testfile.cpp"

Comment: As it's pure C you should use `gcc` and name the file `*.c`.

Comment: thanks...can u suggest me a good ebook on working of memory...?

Comment: As you're using g++, this question should be tagged c++, not c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are actually using C++ which supports dynamic array sizing like that, consider what an argument of 20995 does: it dynamically allocates 20995 times `sizeof lb_data_US` (which is about 600) for a total allocation of 12.5+ megabytes.  Few environments support such a large stack size.  Instead, use the heap via `malloc()` supported in many environments for process limit sorts of sizes.

Comment: yeah...i got the first point...but what is the difference....can we assign such large memories in heap using malloc().?

Comment: Yes indeed.  Malloc allows use of all available memory and then some on virtual memory systems.

Comment: thanks...can u suggest me a good ebook on working of memory...?

Comment: No, C++ *doesn't* support variable-length arrays (it doesn't really need them, since it has things like `std::vector`).  VLAs were added to C by the 1999 ISO standard, and are also supported as an extension by some compilers, including gcc.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x=atoi(argv[1]);
lb_data_US lb_local[x];
```

You cannot specify a size of an array allocated in stack using an `int` whose value is determined on runtime. It works only [in C99 mode or as an GCC's extension to C90](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). If your compiler doesn't support it use [`malloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) instead.

```
lb_data_US *lb_local = malloc(x * sizeof(lb_data_US));
```

If you'd like to force the compiler to use a C99 mode, it can be usually achieved by adding `-std=c99` to compiler's execution arguments.

Comment: but if that is the case then how can it assugn value when the value entered is smaller int...

Comment: kindly pardon my ignorance...i new in programming

Comment: Jan, What you say used to be true, but is no longer true in C99.  See: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Comment: jayant, do you mean assigning a value to an element of the array allocated with malloc? Go for `array[index].field_name = ...` and take a look at `strcpy` or `memcpy` in case of strings.

Comment: hmm yeah i got your point ...infact
 "lb_data_US *lb_local = malloc(x * sizeof(lb_data_US));"
this was giving an error saying invalid conversion from void * to lb_data_US *....but it worked ...thsnks for ur help guys..
cheers